# Does peerjs with peerjs-server requires a stun/turn/ice server in order to work properly?

Tags: webrtc, peerjs

I'm building a videoconference module for an application,
I'm using peerjs and peerjs-server behind nginx, the video
and audio streams work well but sometimes the data channels just wont open, and I get this error

```
Error: Negotiation of connection to 5fb2c133-7586-47b0-abf7-0f0832677e92 failed
```

usually just reloading the browser a few times makes it work but it is obviously not ideal, help is appreciated, I have read somewhere that one needs a turn/stun/ice server in order for webrtc to work, but I don't know if exactly what I need if I'm working with peerjs-server, shouldn't the media connections have issues too?

thanks for reading, hope someone can help me.

Comment: i believe `peerjs-server` only works as signaling server (passing users peer id to each other ) u still need  turn/stun server .... i think twilio offers free turn/stun server up to 1g usage try it and see